# How to use redis endpoint in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, cache, redis, cm-redissession

i am unable to add redis endpoint in magento 2.1 below is my code that i added in "etc/env.php"

Please let me know what i am missing

```
 'cache' =>
    array(
       'frontend' =>
       array(
          'default' =>
          array(
             'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
             'backend_options' =>
             array(
                'server' => 'xyz-redis-latest.opb3io.0001.aps1.cache.amazonaws.com',
                'database' => '0',
                'port' => '6379'
                ),
        ),
        'page_cache' =>
        array(
          'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
          'backend_options' =>
           array(
             'server' => 'xyz-redis-latest.opb3io.0001.aps1.cache.amazonaws.com',
             'port' => '6379',
             'database' => '1',
             'compress_data' => '0'
           )
        )
      )
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Backend cache on Redis**

use below sample command:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --cache-backend=redis --cache-backend-redis-server=xxxxxxxxxxx --cache-backend-redis-db=0
```

**For Page Cache on Redis**

use below sample command:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --page-cache=redis --page-cache-redis-server=xxxxxxxxxxx --page-cache-redis-db=1
```

After above commands `env.php` will be updated automatically.

Both cache could be save on same redis server but it will use different databases 0 and 1

**Note: For local redis cache, use 127.0.0.1**